# Remove a character once

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string

```
  NSString *str = @"[\"a\" : \"b\" , \"c\" : \"d\", \"e\" : \"f\" ,]" ;
```

I want to remove comma (,) only i.e. if the string has comma only towards the end of the string, it should be replaced with a blank charachter like @"". Comma should not be removed if it appears in the start or the middle of the string. So the final string should be

```
 ["a" : "b" , "c" : "d", "e" : "f"]
```

instead of

```
 ["a" : "b" , "c" : "d", "e" : "f",]
```

Comment: There is no "blank character". Do you mean empty string? Also, is the real specification to remove a comma if it appears before a "]" at the end of the string?

Comment: Which part is so difficult?  All you have to do is save colon-separated elements in an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know I understand exactly what you want to do  but from your example you mast want to remove last come. If there is always closing bracket ']' at the end you can use;

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" ,]" withString:@"]"];
```

Hope this is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = @"[\"a\" : \"b\" , \"c\" : \"d\", \"e\" : \"f\" ,]";

int index = string.length - 1;

while (index-- >= 0) {

    if ([string characterAtIndex:index] == ',')
        break;
}

string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1) withString:@""];

NSLog(@"String %@", string); // String ["a" : "b" , "c" : "d", "e" : "f" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick.. It's working fine..

```
   NSMutableArray *subStr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
   NSString *lastString = [subStr lastObject];
  [subStr removeObject:lastString];
   NSString *finalStrin = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[subStr componentsJoinedByString:@","],lastString];
```